# Prove that $\sec x \geq 1+\frac{x^2}{2}$ on $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$.

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Prove that $\sec x \geq 1+\dfrac{x^2}{2}$ on $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$.

We have that $\sin x < x$ on $(0,\frac\pi2)$. Hence $x- \sin x > 0$ on $(0,\frac\pi2)$. Let $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{2}+\cos x.$ Then $f'(x) = x- \sin x$. By the MVT, $\exists x_1\in (0,x)$ such that $f'(x_1) = \dfrac{\frac{x^2}{2}+\cos x - 1}{x}>0\Rightarrow\cos x -1+\dfrac{x^2}{2}>0.$ Now let $g(x) =  \sin x -x +\dfrac{x^3}{6}.$ Then $g'(x) = \cos x - 1 +\dfrac{x^2}{2}$. By the MVT, $\exists x_2 \in (0,x)$ such that $g'(x_2) = \dfrac{\sin x -x + \frac{x^3}{6}}{x} >0\Rightarrow \sin x -x + \dfrac{x^3}{6} > 0$ on $(0,x)$. Let $h(x) = -\cos x - \dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^4}{24} .$ Then $h'(x) = \sin x - x + \dfrac{x^3}{6}$. Since $h(x)$ is continuous, by the MVT, $\exists x_3 \in (0,x)$ such that $h'(x_3) = \dfrac{-\cos x - \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24} +1}{x} >0\Rightarrow \cos x < 1-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^4}{24} $ on $(0,x)$. Since $\cos (x) = \cos (-x)$, and $x \in (0,\frac\pi2)$, $\cos x < 1-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^4}{24}$ on $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$. Hence $\sec x =\dfrac{1}{\cos x} >  \dfrac{1}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}}=1+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^4}{8}+O(x^6) > 1+\dfrac{x^2}{2}$ on $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$.

> I'm quite sure the proof above is correct, but it's way too long for a simple question like this one, so I was wondering if there was a much cleaner, shorter proof?

Comment: Can you expand the Taylor series of $\sec(x)$ and use Taylor's remainder theorem? Is it allowed? Because the third term in the expansion is $\tfrac{5x^4}{24}$ which is always positive in the given interval, hence the conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to prove this for $0 \leq x \leq \pi /2$. Note that $\tan x \geq x$ in this interval because the inequality holds for $x=0$ and the derivative of $tan x -x$, which is $\sec^{2}x-1$ is non-negative. We can now conclude that $\tan x \sec x \geq x$ because $\sec x \geq 1$. Finally Note that the derivative of $\sec x -(1+\frac {x^{2}} 2)$ is non-negative and this function vanishes at $0$. Hence it is non -negative.

Answer (score 0):

Taylor series of $\sec(x)$ around zero is $1+x^2/2 + 5\xi^4/24$ for some $\xi\in [0,x]$ by Taylor's Remainder Theorem. For $x\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, $\xi\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and $ 5\xi^4/24>0$. Therefore, $$\sec(x) = 1+x^2/2 + 5\xi^4/24 >1+x^2/2.$$

*Note that, this argument is only valid in this interval, because $\sec$ may not be analytic in other intervals.*

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{\left(2+x^{2}\right)\cos x}{2}$. Then, $f'(x)=\left(x\cos x-\sin x\right)-\frac{x^{2}\sin x}{2}$. Since $\sin x$ is monotonic and has the same sign as $x$ for $\frac{-\pi}{2}\le x\le \frac{\pi}{2}$, we have $-x\sin x\le0$ and $-\frac{x^2}{2}\sin x$ is monotonically decreasing. But $-x\sin x$ is also the derivative of $\left(x\cos x-\sin x\right)$, so that is monotonically decreasing too and so is the sum, $f'(x)$. Then, $f'(x)$ is nonnegative over over $\frac{-\pi}{2}\le x\le 0$, has a root at $0$ and nonpositive over $0\le x\le \frac{\pi}{2}$. Then, $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing over $\frac{-\pi}{2}\le x\le 0$, maximal at $(0,1)$ and decreasing over $0\le x\le \frac{\pi}{2}$. Therefore, $f(x)\le 1$, so $\displaystyle 1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}\le{\sec x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$ \sec x-1=\int_0^x\sec t\tan tdt.$$
So what one has to show that
$$ \int_0^x\sec x\tan tdt\ge\frac {x^2}2=\int_0^x tdt.$$
Suppose $0\le x\le\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $t\in[0,x]$. Let
$$ f(t)=\sin t-t\cos^2t $$
and then
$$ f'(t)=\cos t-\cos^2t+t\sin(2t)\ge0. $$
This means that $f(t)$ is increasingin in $[0,x]$ and so
$$ f(t)\ge f(0)=0$$
which implies
$$ \sec t\tan t\ge t $$
Therefore
$$ \sec x-1=\int_0^x\sec t\tan tdt\ge \int_0^xtdt=\frac{x^2}{2} $$
or
$$ \sec x \ge 1+\frac{x^2}{2}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Due to symmetry, consider $x\ge0$ below,

$$\sec x -1-\dfrac{x^2}{2}=\int_0^x (\tan u\sec u - u)du\ge \int_0^x (\tan u - u)du
=\int_0^xdu \int_0^t (\sec^2 t-1)dt\ge0$$